# Why index out of range error is coming

Tags: python-2.7

```
t=0  
a=5
b=[] 
b[0]=1 
while a!=0:    
    b[t+1]=a-1    
    a=a-1    
    t+=1  
print b
```

in this program it is giving error of index out of range for b[0]=1 
,actually expecting this b= [1,4,3,2,1,0]

Comment: MCVE: `l = ['some_value']; l[1] = 'new'`. It raises exception because bracket notation is used to retrieving data, not setting it. Use `list.append()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign value list. 
Use this code for **expected output**:

```
t=0  
a=5
b=[]
b.append(1)

while a!=0:
   b.append(a-1)
   a=a-1

print b
```